# MySQL support in Visual Studio 2022 add connection

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I know MySQL for Visual Studio only works on VS2019 actually not support for VS2022.

I use the SSDKToSql T4 Script or the great Extension for Reverse Engieer  [EFCorePowerTool](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools)

Is there a way to add the Connection / Datasource to VS2022 manuell?